# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint, but part of the key doesn't exist in table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with column1, column2, column3 and column4. The primary key is (column1, column2, column3).

When I tried to execute "UPDATE public.table SET column1= value_x;" I get :

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> "pk_table " DETAIL:  Key (column1, column2, column3)=(value_x, value_y, value_z) already
> exists.

But when I do "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = value_x;" I get 0 results.
So logically the primary key that cause the error doesn't exist.

Does anyone know why I get this error ?
Thanks

PS : i'm on postgres.

Comment: `UPDATE public.table SET column1= value_x;` will set the value od `column1` on *every* row.

Comment: Yes it is what I try to do

Comment: *...column1 = value_x;" I get 0 results* is true because the UPDATE failed. You got the error because in your data there are rows that have the same values for `value_y` and `value_z` with the only thing making those rows a legitimate PK is that the value of `value_x` differed. Your UPDATE tried to make `value_x` the same across all rows and that caused the PK constraint to be violated.

Comment: Ok I get it thanks a lot, do you have a request to get those rows ?

Comment: Not tested: `select column2, colum3 from table group by column2, column3 having count(*) > 1`

Comment: I find it with the query : SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column2, colum3) IN (SELECT column2, colum3 FROM table GROUP BY(column2, colum3) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);

Answer (score 1):

you have a p_key of combination of 3 columns, if you use update statement, it will update throughout the table, and at certain point, the combination of column1,2,3 becomes same, causing violation of p_key, hence throwing error.